# How to save the average and standard deviation from a Jmeter listener

Tags: csv, jmeter, darwin

I'm not sure if this is doable in JMeter.  Is there a way to save the average response time and std deviation that's shown in the "View Results in Table" Listener to the results file?  The csv file that's saved has all the data in the table, it just doesn't have the average and std. dev. in it which would be nice to have.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Here's an image from my Jmeter. [image]

**EDIT:** If there's a way to do it with another Listener, I'm all ears, although:

1. The info on each response is useful to me so I would still use "View Results in Table"
2. I tried saving with all those Listeners you see in the jpg and they were all the same when
   saved as csv.

**EDIT#2:** I need to automate this so whatever solution there is, hopefully we can tell jmeter to do it from the command line too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average response time and deviation cannot be recorded, they have to be **calculated** after the run.

So for instance if you run JMeter in non-GUI mode as

```
jmeter -n -t path_to_jmx_file -l path_to_jtl_file
```

it'll produce CSV output file. After opening it in MS Excel or equivalent you should be able to add a couple of simple formulae to get these values.

Besides you can open results `.jtl` file with any JMeter Listener and they'll do the calculations for you. So there is no need to keep listeners during performance test run as they do consume memory, feed results file to those, which are matching your expected reporting after the run.

Another option is using [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) which provides nice HTML output.

Finally you can consider using a [JMeter Plugin](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter) which uploads results to the cloud, builds professional looking and easy readable tables and graphs and has capability to compare different test run results. Check out [sample report](https://a.blazemeter.com/report/r-ec528242f1e891d) for details

Comment: thx for the suggestion and tip.  I thought jmeter could do it on the fly since the "View Results in Table" listener displays a running Average and Std Dev.  I need to eventually run jmeter in a script/non-GUI mode so i don't think the script can open excel to run the output thru formulas  ;)  Unless there's a way to do this thru jmeter from cmd line after the run, I guess I have to write a script to calculate this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `View Results in Table` for anything but developing and/or debugging as if you'll leave it enabled during performance run you'll have out-of-memory.

See http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips

Comment: Thanks for the article and pointing out Listeners are affecting my testing. Is there a way to pass in a csv file to jmeter on the cmd line and have it calculate these things for me? I didn't find a cmd line option that allowed me to do that.  From the UI, like you said, I was able to load output from an earlier test run into a Summary Report listener and it calculated the std dev and avg for me so I'm hoping I can do that from cmd line too.

Comment: It isn't possible. See Calculator class http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java?view=markup on how JMeter does calculation of dev and avg response time. You need `addValue()` method

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use **summary report** Listener which lists Avg. response time, Std. deviation etc. and results can be saved to file.

Comment: thx for the suggestion.  Do you know if there's a way to save what you see in the UI for Summary Report into a file automatically?  I can manually click on the "Save Table Data" for Summary Report and save it but if I need to do this automatically in a script, how can I control this Listener to output what it provides graphically?  Right now, the "Write results to file" option saves the same information that the "View Results in Table" listener displays/saves.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think it needs your own customisation to read output from Jmeter GUI as you shown in above picture.
If your are really interested you can modify the jmeter Tree visualizer(`package org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.TableVisualizer`)
element in source code.